# (Co)homology of free symmetric algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

Let $V$ be a (co)chain complex, and let $Sym(V)$ be the free differential graded-commutative algebra generated by $V$. Definition and examples below in case you don't know what I mean.

> Question: What's the cleanest proof that $H^*(Sym(V)) \cong Sym(H^*(V))$?

All my proofs are a little messy, using the gradings on Sym(V) coming from cohomological grading and degree by the number of products. Though I expect all proofs to use this bigrading, a clean, succinct proof would be very appreciated!

Definition: $Sym(V)$ is the free dg tensor algebra on $V$, modded out by the relation $v_1 v_2 = (-1)^{|v_1| |v_2|} v_2 v_1$. The differential is given by the Leibniz rule: $d(uv) = (du)v + (-1)^{|u|}u dv$.

Example: If $V$ is concentrated in degree 0, $Sym(V)$ is the usual free commutative algebra generated by $V$. If $V$ is concentrated in even degrees, the underlying vector space of $Sym(V)$ is the usual free commutative algebra, but $Sym(V)$ has a grading where $|v_1 \ldots v_n| = |v_1| + \ldots + |v_n|$. The differential is zero by the Leibniz rule.

Example: If $V$ is concentrated in odd degrees, $Sym(V)$ has underlying vector space given by the exterior algebra generated by $V$. It has no differentials by the Leibniz rule, but has grading $|v_1 \ldots v_n| = |v_1| + \ldots + |v_n|$.

Comment: You say that "all [your] proofs" are a little messy, which implies you have multiple proofs.  Could you say a little bit about these proofs so that, as people search for new proofs, they have both inspiration and foreknowledge of what to avoid (so as not to just recreate what you have)?  Also, do you have any proofs that make explicit use of the universal property of Sym?

Comment: My proofs were even wrong in the generality of the question; I was implicitly using characteristic zero. Thank you, Justin Young.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This requires some sort of assumption on the ground ring, or on $V$ or both. Consider, for example, the ground ring $\mathbb Z/2$ and the complex $V = \{a\to da\}$ where $a$ has degree $n>1$. Then, clearly $Sym(H^*(V))$ is $\mathbb Z/2$ in degree zero. But, $a^2$ represents a non-zero class in $H^{2n}(Sym(V))$. You should assume that the ground field has characteristic zero.

Edit: By induction you can prove the result by considering the filtration $Sym^n(V) = \bigoplus_{i=0}^n V^{\otimes i}/\Sigma_i$. Then, the quotient $Sym^{n+1}(V)/Sym^n(V) = V^{\otimes (n+1)}/\Sigma_{n+1}$, and $\mathbb k$ is a projective $\mathbb k [\Sigma_{n+1}]$ module, thus $H^*(V^{\otimes (n+1)}/\Sigma_{n+1}) \cong H^*(V)^{\otimes (n+1)}/\Sigma_{n+1}$. Now induction tells you that $H^*(Sym^n(V)) \cong Sym^n(H^*(V))$, and thus the result.